# Creating a Windows application that has to call bash scripts and Python scripts that use Linux-based modules?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, python, cygwin

I want to create a Windows application that calls bash scripts and Python scripts that use Linux-based modules. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

1. What would be the cleanest way to do this, and in such a way that a new user can simply run one install file that will install the Windows application?
2. If someone needs to do something like this, do people generally have the user install something such as Cygwin as part of the installation of the Windows application? Or can some sort of DLL be generated to use the bash/python feature I need?

On the scripts side, the scripts will still change in the future, so having to port everything to work with Windows is not ideal.

The main issues I see so far are bash scripts, Linux-based python packages like pexpect, and directory path slashes and locations (e.g. the tmp directory in Linux)

My thoughts are that I can either:

a) Add conditional checks for the OS type in the Python scripts and execute the compatible code depending on the OS; and have the user install something like win-bash to handle the calling of bash files. OR ...

b) Require the user to install Cygwin, and have minimal changes in the scripts to support anything that it can't handle.

Comment: The B option is more simple as application development; the packages available are a lot https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html. Question: is it a console only or do you need graphic interface ?

Comment: It'll be with a graphical interface.

Comment: Than be sure to test with X interface and be sure to define which cygwin packages will be needed by your user.